# how to fix owlcarousel not displaying

Tags: laravel, owl-carousel

I'm using Laravel Framework 6.20.16.

I add CSS links and js scripts to my template file and its links to my index.blade.php file
using @extends('layouts.sewaTemplate') as usually .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/owl.carousel.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/owl.theme.default.min.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/owl.carousel.min.js') }}"></script>
```

and I add script code at the bottom of the index page like this

```
@section('scripts')
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
items: 4,
loop: true,
margin: 10,
autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 1000,
autoplayHoverPause: true
});
$('.play').on('click', function() {
owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000])
})
$('.stop').on('click', function() {
owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
})
})
</script>
@endsection
```

and I add this HTML code to the index page

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
            <h4>1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>3</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>4</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>5</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>6</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>7</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>8</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>9</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>10</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>11</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
            <h4>12</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="button secondary play">Play</a> 
        <a class="button secondary stop">Stop</a> 
</section>
```

**but there is show only Play and Stop **

and there is an error in the console

> app.js:49777  Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js): TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'parseComponent' of undefined
> at parse (home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/node_modules/@vue/component-compiler-utils/dist/parse.js:15)
> at Object.module.exports (home/sameera/Desktop/sewa/sewa/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js:67)
> at Object../resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue (app.js:49777)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
> at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:49712)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
> at Object.0 (app.js:49799)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
> at app.js:84
> at app.js:87 ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue @ app.js:49777
> **webpack_require** @ app.js:20 ./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:49712
> **webpack_require** @ app.js:20 0 @ app.js:49799
> **webpack_require** @ app.js:20 (anonymous) @ app.js:84 (anonymous) @ app.js:87

Comment: Check the browser console for error logs if any

Comment: no, errors in console